# Boundedness and convergence of $x_{n+1} = x_n ^2-x_n +1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $x_0 = \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x_{n+1} = x_n ^2-x_n +1$.

I am asked to study the boundedness of $(x_n)$ and then asked if $(x_n)$ converges. How can I show that $(x_n)$ is bounded?

I have noted that $$x_{n+1}-x_n = (x_n-1)^2\geq 0$$ so $x_n$ is increasing. 
Suppose that $(x_n)$ converges, then $l = l^2-l+1$ so $l = 1$. This means that the sequence converges only when $\alpha \leq 1$. And so $(x_n)$ is bounded above by $1$ if $\alpha\leq 1$ (since an increasing sequence converges to its supremum) otherwise the sequence is not bounded above.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: If it is bounded, then it converges. And if it converges, then it converges to 1. I agree with you up to here.

Comment: But you say if $\alpha \leq 1$, then it is bounded. How do you really justify this?

Comment: If $\alpha \leq 1$ then $(x_n)$ converges, so $(x_n)$ is bounded since it is monotone.

Comment: That is circular. Suppose you haven't shown it converges yet. Your argument is "its bounded because it converges"

Comment: You actually have to show that alpha <= 1 implies bounded.

Comment: Is this the correct reasoning: $(x_n)$ is bounded $\iff$ $(x_n)$ converges $\iff (x_n)$ converges to $1 \iff \alpha \leq 1$?

Comment: I think you need to make an actual argument to do with the sequence itself, ie the argument won't come for free by manipulating definitions and standard facts. You could (for example) look at the line you wrote down where you said "I have noted that". It says more than increasing, it tells you explicitly what the increment is. Maybe that helps etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is correct for $\alpha\ge0$, but you have not considered the case  $\alpha<0$.

We have that $x<x^2-x+1<1$ if $x\in(0,1)$. It follows that if $\alpha\in(0,1)$ then $\{x_n\}$ is increasing and bounded by $1$. Then it converges, and the limit must be $1$.

Comment: Is the line reasoning used in this question: 

$(x_n)$ is bounded $\iff$ $(x_n)$ converges $\iff (x_n)$ converges to $1 \iff \alpha \leq 1$

Comment: Convergence implies boundedness, but not the other way around. Boundedness AND monotonicity imply convergence. If $\alpha\ge0$ then $\{x_n\}$ is increasing; if moreover $\alpha\le1$, then $\{x_n\}$ is bounded. If $\alpha>1$ then $\{x_n\}$ is unbounded, and if $\alpha<0$ then $x_1>1$.

Comment: I am following the logic like this: If $(x_n)$ converges, it converges to 1. So if $\alpha>1$ then $(x_n)$ cannot converge and so $(x_n)$ is not bounded since it is monotone increasing. But then how can we say anything about $\alpha\leq 1$?

Comment: Could you please write out how the answer should be structured using the ideas in my post, I think I am confusing myself.

Comment: I have added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $x_{n+1}=1-x_n(1-x_n)$. Thus $x_{n+1}\in[0,1]$ if and only if $x_n\in[0,1]$. Thus the sequence is bounded above by $1$ if and only if $\alpha\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Case $\alpha >1$, show by induction that
$$x_n-1\geq  \alpha ^n(\alpha -1)$$
Proof:
$$x_{n+1}-1=x_n{}^2-x_n=x_n\left(x_n-1\right)\geq  \alpha  \alpha ^n(\alpha -1)=\alpha ^{n+1}(\alpha -1)$$

This shows $x_n$ diverges

Case $\alpha <0$, $x_1>1$ so we are back to the previous case

Case $0\leq  \alpha \leq  1$, $x_n$ is bounded so it converges