# sequence $(x_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ ; $x_{n+1}=x_{n}^2-x_{n}+1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have the following sequence $(x_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ ; $x_{n+1}=x_{n}^2-x_{n}+1$
I need to find $x_1$ such that  $(x_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ is convergent.

I found that $(x_n-1)^{2}>0$ so $x_n$ is increasing.

Also, If I note the limit with $L$ I get $L^2-2l+1=0$ so $L=1$

If $x_1>1$ and $x_n$ is increasing result that $x_n>1$  How to continue?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868333/boundedness-and-convergence-of-x-n1-x-n-2-x-n-1

Comment: If $x_1>1$ the sequence is not convergent. How about for $x_n=1$ or for $0\le x_n<1$?